# Protobuf serializer using Dynamic message

Tags: protobuf-java

I am trying to use probuf serializer provided by confluent . I am constructing Dynamic message and publishing it to kafka cluster . But am not able to consume same message using kafka consumer . Does producing and consuming Dynamic message is possible using prootbuf serializer provided by confluecnt. I can see examples of consuming but not producer

Trying to use confluent protobuf serializer